# Can you replace first special character with a comma, and remove other special characters from the cell?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to make my sheet easier to use by copy-pasting the data I need and then referring to the cells in another place on my sheet. When pasted, the data uses dots instead of commas between integers and decimals. This causes the sheet to change the data values in a strange way. For example, `98.04` was replaced by `98:04:00.000`, and `20.39` by `20.39.00`. I know it happens because the sheet wants there to be a decimal comma, but I do not understand how it works or why one of the two aforementioned got colons between numbers while the other retained its dots.

Anyhow, I would like the values in my cells that reference the copy-pasted values to be real numbers, with decimal commas. What I was thinking was to either to change all dots and colons to commas then remove any commas following the first, or to remove any dots or colons following the first then change the remaining one to a comma. However, I have no knowledge of how to do this, which is why I'm asking you folks.

Edit: Link to a copy of my sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17-qHsr3Pky2_5aSRb7l4K5uB9JKStAxIK8qwgfd1vxE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I do not understand how it works or why one of the two aforementioned got colons between numbers while the other retained its dots

there are 2 versions of syntaxes US using commas `,` and EU using semicolons `;`. it always can be selected here:

[image: 0]

---

```
=(REGEXEXTRACT(A1&""; "\d+")&","&REGEXEXTRACT(A1&""; ":(\d+)"))*1
```

[image: 0]

and ArrayFormula would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A&""; "\d+")&","&
 REGEXEXTRACT(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A&""; "."; ":"); ":(\d+)")*1))
```

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(D64:D71); "\d+")&","&
 REGEXEXTRACT(TO_TEXT(SUBSTITUTE(D64:D71; "."; ":")); ":(\d+)"))*1)
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O9GIG6Q9EPQv276_o15ILYxHUwwbPTieqNMoVx0oTLg/edit#gid=0)

Comment: The first one outputs #N/A, and the second one outputs #VALUE!
After searching a littlebit I found and tried the TO_TEXT function, but then the output was 98,4, as opposed to the expected 98,04.

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you for the help, I very much appreciate it!